# What triggers a testimonial match?

Tags: football-manager-2016

In Football Manager 2016, it's possible to play a friendly match in honor of a player. What triggers this occurence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A testimonial match is avaiable as a Friendly Match option if:

- The player has been in a club for 10 years (accumulative)
- The player has announced a retirement date

---

*Note that the player doesn't need to be a favorite member, icon or legend. It just requires him to be for 10 years in  total at a club. He doesn't need to be Club/Nation grown.*